# avoid flashing Error: [object Object] when using renderDT in Shiny

Tags: object, reactive, dt, shinyapps

I have some Shiny code with the following basic structure as part of the server function:

```
x <- reactive( *some code here* )

output$table <- renderDT( x() |> datatable(*some formatting options*) )
```

When I run this, it works fine, except... I briefly see the following red words flash in the area that is later occupied by the correct datatable object

```
Error: [object Object]
```

It seems like the rendering is preceding the evaluation of the reactive x.

As I said, after a half-second, the red error message goes away, and the data table is properly rendered. For a "nicer" app, I would like to avoid having the user see this message.

I have tried to figure out using `validate`, `req`, `freeze`, and some other such commands - but can't seem to get anything to work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated (sorry - no reproducible example since the code/data is big and the data contains proprietary information). I am assuming it's because the calculations in x() take some time, but maybe there I have some fundamental misunderstanding (I'm new to Shiny).